# Why can I declare an object which is of the type of an interface, and instantiate this object as another type?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I am new on Java and Android. I want to understand the following line:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

My doubt is: it is declared an object called listMap, which is of the type List of Map, right? But it is instantiated as an ArrayList. Sorry for the simple question, but Why is this possible?

ps1: I know List is an interface, so I can't instantiate an object of an interface type.

ps2: I can declare listMap as being of the ArrayList type. What is the advantage of declare it as a List.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html . public class ArrayList<E> .... implements List<E>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ps1: I know List is and interface, so I can't instantiate and object of its type.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

You are right, `List` is an *Interface* hence you will not be able to instantiate an *Interface*. You need to use some implementing class of the interface to instantiate. `ArrayList` is an implementation class of interface `List` and being used in the able statement.

> ps2: I can declare listMap as being of the type ArrayList. What is the advantage of declare it as a List.

You can always, use `ArrayList` in the left side as well i.e.

```
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

**Advantage of using Interface:**  If you want to use your variable object(listMap) across the classes then better to use the *Interface* as type, but if your variable object (lsitMap) locally within your program locally, then I don't think there is any added advantage.

Now you will think about `Map`, which is again an *Interface*. Please note that, you are not instantiating the `Map` object through above statement. You are just mentioning that your `listMap` list will contain the element of `Map` type.

Again when you will try to instantiate elements to add in the `listMap`, you will need an implementation class of `Map` interface e.g `HashMap` as below:

```
   List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

   Map<String, String> lsitMapElement1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
   lsitMapElement1.put("key1", "value1");
   listMap.add(lsitMapElement1 );

   Map<String, String> lsitMapElement2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
   lsitMapElement2.put("key2", "value2");
   listMap.add(lsitMapElement2);
```

Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But I can declare listMap as being of the type ArrayList. What is the advantage of declare it as a List.

Comment: @user1771682 I was updating the answer already. Please refer the new paragraph added in the top section of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. I am already using HashMap in my code.

Comment: Done! Really I think there is not advantage in my case. My application is just an example, and this variavel is only used at the main activity class. So I think it was declared as List only due to good programming practice. Thank you again.

Comment: @user1771682: That's correct. It's good programming practice.

Comment: " but if your variable object (lsitMap) locally within your program locally, then I don't think there is any added advantage". `public void myMethod(List<MyObject> list)`, remember that `list` is local there. If you were to use `ArrayList` there than you would have to change your method signature. So, I wouldn't consider that as a bad advice.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`. That is an `ArrayList` is-a `List`.

And you can assign an instance of subtype to a variable of it's supertype. Or, where a supertype some is expected, you can substitute it with some substype .

---

You achieve object-polymorphism (with inheritance) with that and your code is not dependent on some specific implementation. Rather anytime in the future if you suddenly realize that `ArrayList` is not going to work and you need some other implementation of `List` then you can easily switch to that implementation without affecting the rest of your code.

This is the reason that they say, "Always code against the interface whenever possible."

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But I can declare listMap as being of the type ArrayList. What is the advantage of declare it as a List

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` class implements the `List` interface, which means that all of the methods defined by `List` have been implemented. Other code doesn't need to know that this is an `ArrayList` specifically, just that it implements all the `List` methods.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But I can declare listMap as being of the type ArrayList. What is the advantage of declare it as a List

Comment: Your `ArrayList` object just happens to contain `Map` objects, but it will still implement all the methods of `List`. You could use another object that implements `List` just as easily if it provides the specific functionality you need.